# Question about regular bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

A bipartite graph with partite sets U and W is called balanced if |U| = |W|.
Let G be a regular bipartite graph with at least one edge. Prove that G is balanced.

A regular graph means that every vertex has the same degree this implys that (using the bipartite property) the number of vertices in U = W again by it being bi partite and having vertices of equal degree implys that |U| = |W|.

At least in my head that makes sense any hint how to prove it?

Comment: A sketch of a proof: Suppose that $G$ is $d$-regular bipartite with bipartition $U,W$.  For each $u\in U$ by the fact that the graph is $d$-regular there will be $d$ edges leaving $U$ with the other ends in $W$ since $G$ is bipartite.  Each $u$ contributes $d$ such ends.  Summing over all $u\in U$ this is $d|U|$ total ends with some unknown number of them overcounted.  Each vertex in $W$ corresponds to exactly $d$ of those ends as well, again by regularity, leading us to knowing $|W|=(d|U|)/d$.  This could be cleaned up, I'm sure, but it has some of the important observations.

Comment: The idea, for the record, being the "shepherd's principle," that to count the number of sheep in a field (*containing only sheep and all sheep have four legs*) you may instead count the number of legs and divide by four.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out now ^^ if you post the top as answer and ill accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the degree of every node be $d$ (and since the graph has at least one edge, $d>0$). Then the number of edges associated with nodes in $U$ is $|U|d$, and the number of edges associated with nodes in $W$ is $|W|d$. Every edge in the bipartite graph connects a node in $U$ with a node in $W$, thus the total number of edges associated with the two parts is the same.

Thus $|U|d = |W|d$ and $|U| = |W|$

Comment: If $d>|U|/2$ then the graph must be connected.